# Using Jquery bootstrap-modal, prevent clicking on anything except site's header

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

So I have a modal that opens and block everything in my page (as should be), I achieve this by using this:

```
$('#mycoolmodal').modal({
            backdrop: 'static',
            keyboard: false

        });
```

But I want to be able to click on a certain div that is the sites header. I also want the modal to be centered with regards to the header (so it wont overlap with it, if the modal is too big than the user should scroll)

I am aware that I can just change the z-index of that div but it wont help me with the positioning.

is it possible with the default modal? if not, what is the easiest way (and smartest) to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just wrap your html section, excluding header, with another <div class="popup"> and you can use code on this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8462907

Comment: Its almost the answer, I use bootstrap modal, so I run it by executing $("mymodal").modal(); , in the answer you provided they use dialogs

Comment: Someone did it, found now (I searched for 30 minutes before submitting the question.. your link provided with the right keywords for the search, thanks.

Comment: This have been answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21555585/bootstrap-modal-window-inside-another-div

Comment: It is good if I was able to help 